# What is the most efficient way to change the UI of the items in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Suppose I have RecyclerView with hundreds of items. There are a few different view types. When I click on an item it has to change its UI. As I see it there are two options:

- change the item to a different view type and notify the adapter that it changed so that it can inflate a new view to display the new state.
- have both views in a single xml file. only one is visible at any time.  Toggle between them using the setVisibility function when the state changes.

there are a lot of articles online about heterogeneous RecyclerViews using lots of view types, but i have yet seen one about the best practices when item views dynamically change and the RecyclerView becomes more heterogeneous over time.
which method is best to change an existing view in a recycler view? what are the tradeoffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tradeoffs are pretty obvious.

- Both UIs in a single View: depending on your views, this might:

  - Make the Views heavy to inflate and layout
  - Slow down the binding process, since you have to bind both UIs
  - Eventually, lag down the scrolling process.

On the other hand, you have a fast, precise control over what Views should change appearance at a certain time. Having both UIs in the same place allows for finer animations and transitions between one state and another.

- Different View types: I think your case is not why view types were created in the first place - they are meant for having different childs at the same time, in different positions of the list. This:

  - Might slow down the transition. You have to be extremely careful on how you tell the adapter to reload the objects. As you can read anywhere, you might want to avoid `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which reloads any object, and rather use `notifyItemChanged()` or such. This requires some work and attention.
  - Does not allow (not easily, at least) for visual transition between one state and another.

The answer is that, IMO, only you can know. You should ask yourself:

- Are these Views complex? Do they have a deep hierarchy? Would having both of them reduce performance (e.g. in the binding part)?
- Would it be easy to understand which views are changed, and call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` in the second case? Reloading the whole dataset has a huge impact on performance, if you have lots of items.
- Do you need some visual transition between one state and another? Maybe you want both UIs to fit into a single container (like different informations in a CardView)? If this is mandatory, then option 1 is better.
- Do you have more than 2 UIs? If so, I would go with view types, so as not to host too many views in a single child layout.

and similar questions.